# Multiple Formulas in one Cell for hotel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to create a housekeeping spreadsheet where when a room number is entered into a cell a 0 or 1 (0 is for studio and 1 is for a 1 bedroom) is automatically populated in another cell. I have tried nested formulas but it doesn't seem to be working.

Rooms 101,102,131 through 136, 201, 202, 231 through 236, 301, 302 and 331 through 336 should return a value of 1.

Room 103-130, 203-230 and 303-330 should return a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new sheet named `roomtype` to the workbook and in column A enter the room numbers. In column B enter the `1` or `0` for each room. Then go back to the sheet where you want the formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,roomtype!A:B,2,0)
```

where A3 is the cell that has the entered room number.

The first parameter to `VLOOKUP` is a value specifying what value to look up.

The second is the range from which to look up the value, matching the lookup value with what is entered in the leftmost column of the range.

The third specifies which column of the range to pull a looked up value from.

The fourth is a boolean (true or false) that says if the match should be exact, or if it should  be a range lookup. If it is a range lookup you don't have to specify each value in the list, but only enter the value for which the returned value needs to change. This could let you shorten the list of rooms in `roomtype`, but it is cleaner to list them all and use exact match. That way if you accidentally type in a non-existent room number it will alert you by putting `#N/A` in the cell.

Comment: This is awesome thank you so much! I have a few questions - I'm stuck here: =VLOOKUP(C8,roomtype!A2:B109,) What is the col_index_num and the [range_lookup]? Where do I get those values from?

Comment: They will most likely match the 2 and 0 that I used. 2 because the 1 or 0 for the room type should have been in column B which should be the second in that range, and 0 because it represents false, and we want an exact match.

Comment: I have the room number cell where we will enter the room number starting in C8 and the Room type where it should populate starting in D8 so would it be 3,0? I'm really sorry that I'm so slow! Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: The column number (2) is relative to the range, in your case `A2:B109` (A=1, B=2) which could also be written `$A$2:$B$109` which would keep the position of the lookup range fixed if the formula is copied or moved around the page it is on.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? :-( I have this: =VLOOKUP(C8,roomtype!A1:B109,2,FALSE)                                                                I wish I could send you a screenshot on here!!!

Comment: That looks right. Is there a room number in cell C8? Double check the roomtype sheet and verify that there are room numbers in column A and values in column B.

Comment: Also I'm putting this formula into C8 - that's the right place to have it right?

Comment: No, if the formula is going in C8, it is trying to look at itself. It should be looking at another cell for the room number.

Comment: Can it look at the other sheet I have? Like this? =VLOOKUP(roomtype!A2:A109,roomtype!A2:B109,2,FALSE) I'm getting the error when I try to enter a room number that says " The value you entered is not valid. A user has restricted values that can be entered into this cell." But I'm the user that created the spreadsheet...?

Comment: Start with a clean workbook and try to use VLOOKUP there. Experiment for a while. Then when you feel comfortable with VLOOKUP prepare and ask a separate question about the restricted values on your existing sheet.